# How would I access url parameters in Mailer Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following working Preview class:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def invite
    USerMailer.invite
  end
end
```

I'm trying to pass paramaters to the method like so:

```
localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/invite?key1=some_value
```

The server seems to receive them:

```
Parameters: {"key1"=>"some_value", "path"=>"user_mailer/invite"}
```

But when trying to access them with the hash `params`, I get an error.

Can I access these parameters in a Preview method and if so - how?

Comment: How are you accessing the params?

Comment: For the moment I'm just trying with `Rails.logger.info(params)` in the `invite` method.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `undefined local variable or method \`params' for #<UserMailerPreview:0x007f840cfcf110>`

Comment: Hmm I don't think you can access params from your mailer...you will have to pass them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug into the code behind the mailer preview system and discovered that, unfortunately, none of the request parameters are passed to the preview class, and are thus inaccessible to the preview.

The relevant controller action is in railties: [Rails::MailersControlller#preview](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/mailers_controller.rb#L22). Here, you can see it calling [ActionMailer::Preview#call](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/preview.rb#L64) and just passing the name of the "email" (ie: the appropriate method in the preview).

Comment: if my PR https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20646  get submitted this will be possible, pls `+1` if it's important for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I hacked my way through this one today and came up with this solution and [blog post on extending ActionMailer](https://ruby.unicorn.tv/articles/access-url-request-parameters-from-actionmailer-preview).

```
# config/initializers/mailer_injection.rb

# This allows `request` to be accessed from ActionMailer Previews
# And @request to be accessed from rendered view templates
# Easy to inject any other variables like current_user here as well

module MailerInjection
  def inject(hash)
    hash.keys.each do |key|
      define_method key.to_sym do
        eval " @#{key} = hash[key] "
      end
    end
  end
end

class ActionMailer::Preview
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionMailer::Base
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionController::Base
  before_filter :inject_request

  def inject_request
    ActionMailer::Preview.inject({ request: request })
    ActionMailer::Base.inject({ request: request })
  end
end
```

Comment: This will get access to full `request` object. If you want only `params`, add this line `ActionMailer::Preview.inject({ params: request.params })` inside `inject_request` above.